# Cassandra 3.x to 4.x driver differences

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-driver

Can anyone tell me how to replication this old annotation from the Datastax 3.x series of drivers to the new 4.x series:

```
@Table(
        name = "mytable",
        readConsistency = "LOCAL_ONE",
        writeConsistency = "LOCAL_QUORUM")
```

I got the name down: @CqlName("mytable"), just not the consistencies.

We use mappers exclusively in our code - they are fast, and did a lot of boiler-plate stuff for you in the 3.x driver.  In 4.x, not so much and it's frustrating.  There are some things we rely on that I just cannot figure out - like this.

Also (different question but I'll ask here).  Can I set a profile on a session?  Struggling with that one too.

Comment: can you write things that you're struggling with? Mapper in 4.x is simply different, but it has more functionality compared to the 3.x mapper...

Comment: In this example, how do I make my [Dao] [Insert] have a consistency level of one, and the [Dao] [Select] have a consistency level of quorum.  It can be done if I use plain Statements... but, well, we like the [Mapper].

Comment: In this class... I need the Select and Insert interfaces to have different consistency levels. @@Dao
public interface FieldTestsDao {
 @@Select
 PagingIterable<FieldTests> findById(String id); 

 @@Select
 FieldTests findByKeyFields(String id, String source, String subSource); 

 @@Insert
 void save(FieldTests ft);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [driver upgrade guide says](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/upgrade_guide/#object-mapper):

> the "mapper" and "accessor" concepts have been unified into a single "DAO" component, that handles both pre-defined CRUD patterns, and user-provided queries.

In your case you're switching from `@Table` to `@Entity`, like this:

```java
@Entity
@CqlName("mytable")
class MyPojoClass {

}
```

And then you define [Dao class](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/mapper/daos/) where you define individual operations, like, insert/delete/select:

```java
@Dao
public interface ProductDao {

  @Select
  MyPojoClass findBySomething();

  @Insert
  void save(MyPojoClass cls);

  @Delete
  void delete(MyPojoClass cls);
}
```

these operations could be annotated with `@StatementAttributes` annotation, that has [`consistencyLevel`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.5/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/mapper/annotations/StatementAttributes.html#consistencyLevel--), [`executionProfileName`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.5/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/mapper/annotations/StatementAttributes.html#executionProfileName--), and many other attributes.

P.S. For me, one of the big improvements in new Mapper is that you may use the same Entity class with multiple keyspaces & tables inside the same session...

Comment: I think that documentation should be improved, especially for migrate path... I’ll ask developers about it. In the meantime you can always ask at https://community.datastax.com/ or in the driver mailing list at google groups

Comment: JIRA is created to improve docs: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2712

Comment: This github repo should help you. https://github.com/clun/java-cassandra-driver-from3x-to4x . We do have plan to incorporate in official documentation :